# Simple Scheme REPL for studying SICP?

Tags: linux, web-apps, command-line

I would like a simple read-eval-print loop environment to write and read Scheme snippets while reading [SICP](https://mitpress.mit.edu/sites/default/files/sicp/index.html). I have basically two constraints:

- Must be compliant with Scheme enough to allow running the code examples in the book
- Either browser-based or easy to install (I am on Fedora so a `dnf install` would work for me)

Any recommendations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not "simple" and minimalistic, but still worth a try:

You could install the [DrRacket](https://racket-lang.org/) IDE and then follow the instructions on this web site:
[SICP Collections](https://docs.racket-lang.org/sicp-manual/)

> The sicp collection contains a #lang sicp language ideal for studying the book "Structure and Interpretation of Computer Programs" by Gerald Jay Sussman and Hal Abelson.

BTW, Racket is a Lisp Dialect.

DrRacket is a gratis IDE with several configurable display settings. Learners typically choose the `"#beginning-student language"` settings, and only 50% of all menu items are visible, function check-expect() is imported by default, etc.

Setting `#lang sicp` tweaks the DrRacket IDE in a way such that it is a Scheme IDE.

AFAIR, There are github repos where all SICP code has been ported to Racket Lisp.